# moveToFirst does not work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I  am using `moveToFirst` and it works very well. But this sql query doesnt work. I don't know why. I didn't receive any error.

My query

```
String sqlKomut = "SELECT SHareket.*,CHareket.[Meblag],Cari.AnlikBakiye FROM CHareket , SHareket,Cari WHERE  CHareket.[CariID]=SHareket.[CariID]=Cari.[CariID]= '"+cari.getCariID()+"' AND  SHareket.[Seri]='"+hareket.getSeri()+"' AND SHareket.[Sira]='"+hareket.getSira()+"'AND SHareket.[Tip]='"+hareket.getTip()+"' AND SHareket.[Cins]='"+hareket.getCins()+"' ORDER BY SHareket.[Satir]";
```

and I get my cursor getValue here:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlKomut, null);

if(cursor !=null){

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do {
            eleman.setStrEleman(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Seri")));
            eleman.setIntEleman1(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Sira")));
            eleman.setIntEleman2(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("CariID")));
            eleman.setIntEleman10(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Cins")));
            eleman.setIntEleman11(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Tip")));
            eleman.setIntEleman11(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Satir")));
            eklenenfaturalar.add(eleman);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you running a raw query? does this query work on the db from a sqlite3 tool?

Comment: Try to debug sqlKomut. may be there are some values such as null that makes your query crazy. Or write real sqlKomut value. moveToFirst may not work due to no results found.

Comment: i try sqlkomut and work very well . but come to second if (cursor.moveToFirt) come to false . My query is right

Comment: and my cursor isnt null when debug this query

Comment: The query just doesn't match any rows. First ensure you have data in your database table, then ensure your query matches the rows you want.

Comment: i sure match all rows in my database.

Comment: Something is not right with your query or the content of your database or those values you insert into the query. `cursor.moveToFirst()` will only be `false` if there are exactly 0 result rows and therefore no "first".

Comment: Yes you are so right .And I know that, But my cursor isnt null.

Comment: The cursor is never `null`, the cursor is *empty*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE CHareket.[CariID]=SHareket.[CariID]=Cari.[CariID]= '...'
```

You cannot do multiple comparisons in a single expression like that.
(The comparison returns a boolean value, 0 or 1; any more comparisons will then use this boolean instead of an ID value, e.g., you end up with something like `1=Cari.CariID`.)

To use multiple comparisons, connect them with AND (as you already did with the other ones):

```
WHERE CHareket.[CariID]=SHareket.[CariID]
  AND SHareket.[CariID]=Cari.[CariID]
  AND Cari.[CariID]='...'
  ...
```